# JqGrid : Sorting of a column which have mixed controls; Label and Select

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

JqGrid Default sorting works on Label's Text and Selected Value of Select/Dropdown
Formatter is given below
    `{ name: 'DI', index: 'DI', width: 125, fixed: true, title: false, formatter: BuildDI }`

Based on permission, Label/Dropdown is rendered

```
// Generate Dropdown
function BuildDI(cellvalue, options, rowObject, action) {


    if (bEditPermission == false ) {
            s = getTextBasedOnVal(Arryoptions, val) ;
        }
    }
    else {
        s = '<select OrgVal="' + cellvalue + '"style="width: 100%" class="cSL C" id="_DI_' + options["rowId"] + '" value="' + val + '"><option value=""></option>'
        + Arryoptions.replace("value='" + val + "' >", ' selected="selected" ' + "value=" + val + ">") + '</select>';
    }
    return s;
}
```

Need suggestions to extend JqGrid sorting behaviour to use Selected Text of select control; We have added sort type, still this is not working however sortype func is returning text of dropdown

```
sorttype: function (cellvalue) { return getTextBasedOnVal(Arryoptions, cellvalue); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have successfully resolved this by using rowObject with sortType;

```
 sorttype: function (cellvalue, rowObject) { return GetSortType(cellvalue, rowObject, 'ColIndex'); }
```

Our GetSortType function pick the text from Select Control of rowObject

Answer (score 0):

If you are need sorting, try to use `sortable: true`  and `sortname: 'nome_of_field'` and finally `sortorder: "desc or asc"`

You're welcome

Comment: Sorting is not an issue, we are defining this at Grid Level; var sortorder = "asc";
 var sortname = "Name";
 var cm = jQuery("#jQGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
 if (cm) {
  sortname = jQuery("#jQGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortname');
  sortorder = jQuery("#jQGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'sortorder');
 }

Comment: Use to `editoptions` for create your select, eg: `editoptions: { value: “ID:NAME; ID:NAME; ID:NAME” }`

Comment: You are not getting to the actual issue, everything is working, I need to make the sorting to use Text of select control, JqGrid also provides provisons (sorttype), but it is not working when I have Label and Select two different HTML controls in ONE COLUMN.